# Way to set property depending on other property

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

So, I have this code

```
        Process[] processesManager = Process.GetProcesses();
        List<ProcessInfo> temporaryProcessesList = new List<ProcessInfo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < processesManager.Length; ++i)
        {
            temporaryProcessesList.Add(new ProcessInfo(processesManager[i].ProcessName, processesManager[i].Id, TimeSpan.Zero, "Group"));
        }

        processesList = temporaryProcessesList.GroupBy(d => new {d.Name}).Select(d => d.First()).ToList();
```

This code is used for getting current processes. Then I'm adding those procesess to `temporaryProcessesList`. And instead of simple string "Group" I want to set the property depending of the name of process. For example if process has name leagueoflegends.exe then I would like to set the group to "Games", if its devenv.exe I would like to set the group to "Software development".

And my question is, how to do it the simplest/best way? I was thinking about using Dictionary with string and enum. And comparing the `ProcessName` with string. But maybe there is better way to do it.

`ProcessInfo` is simple class with 4 properties and constructor.

```
public class ProcessInfo
{
    private string Name { get; set; }
    private int Id { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    private string Group { get; set; }

    public ProcessInfo(string name, int id, TimeSpan time, string group)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
        Time = time;
        Group = group;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
public class ProcessInfo
{
    private string _name;
    private string Name
    { 
      get { return _name; }
      set
      {
          _name = value;
          UpdateGroupName();
      }
    }
    private int Id { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    private string Group { get; set; }

    private void UpdateGroupName()
    {
        Group = ProcessNames::GetGroupFromProcessName(Name);
    }

    public ProcessInfo(string name, int id, TimeSpan time)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
        Time = time;
    }
}

internal static class ProcessNames
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _names;

    public static string GetGroupNameFromProcessName(string name)
    {
        // Make sure to add locking if there is a possibility of using
        // this from multiple threads.
        if(_names == null)
        {
            // Load dictionary from JSON file
        }

        // Return the value from the Dictionary here, if it exists.
    }
}
```

This design isn't perfect, but hopefully you see the idea. You could also move the update of the `Group` name to the constructor, but then it would not change the `Group` name if you set the property after construction.

Also, you could clean the interface up by using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and/or dependency injection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Its like way more to write than using dictionary, since i would need to write case for every process. But yeah, thats another solution.

Comment: True, but you could update the `UpdateGroupName` method to read a list of process names and their corresponding group names from a text file, XML file, etc. That way, you could update the group names without rebuilding.

Comment: Hymm.. I want to do it with dictionary. I mean read from json file to dictionary, and I think it would be better way. Don't you think?

Comment: That's what I would do. Create a class that loads & caches the JSON file, then use that class to set the group name based on the process name. I will update the code in the answer to give you an idea.

Answer (score 3):

Using dictionary is the best way to accomplish this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("a.exe", "aGroup");
dictionary.Add("b.exe", "bGroup");

string val;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(processName, out val))
    processInfo.Group = val;
else
    processInfo.Group = "Undefined Group";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But maybe someone would know some other way to do it.